# Can I get a copy of the raw request from python's requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests

code with requests working correctly, using requests_AWS4auth to connect to AWS.

```
 from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
 aws4auth = AWS4Auth(access_key, secret_key, 'us-east-1', 's3')
 response = requests.put(
    url,
    auth=aws4auth,
    data=content)
```

I'm trying to get this to work in aiohttp and asyncio. aiohttp only natively deals with user/password authorization, so I need to pass the actual headers.

I'm trying to get the headers out of the response object, but obviously, they're not in there... those are the headers of the response. I want the headers of the request!

if I do:

```
    request = requests.Request("put",
                               url,
                               auth= aws4auth,
                               data=content)
```

it just puts the aws4auth object in the request object, and has nothing in the headers field.

I'd like to know exactly what is being sent over the wire. Is that possible?

Comment: `response.request` is a copy of the request that this is a response to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requests.Request(...).prepare()` to get the prepared request, and inspect the headers from there:

```py
import requests

r = requests.Request('PUT', 'myurl.com:8000/my/route', json={'some': 'data'}, headers={'hello': 'world'})

prepared = r.prepare()

prepared.headers
{'hello': 'world', 'Content-Length': '16', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```